# How to upgrade Pathfinder Beginner Box games and characters to Pathfinder Core Rules?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-beginner-box

Similar to this question on [Red box to 4e core rules upgrade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4516/what-is-the-upgrade-path-for-characters-generated-with-the-red-box-starter-kit), what problems are there overcome with or good ways to achieve moving games and characters from the Beginner Box rules to Pathfinder Core Rules?

I'm planning to work with the players to pull individual rules/spells/skills etc. in to the game as they would like and am happy to adjudicate any issues that arise from that, but am curious about any game breaking changes.

I know the Beginner Box rules are compatible with the full rules, but are there any problems cause by starting with only a subset of the rules? Can PCs with core character sheets be played alongside PCs with Beginner Box character sheets without problems? Are there any problems with applying new rules piecemeal? Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a lot of changes, but I wouldn't call any of them game breaking. Most if not all of the rules are expanded/enhanced in the full rulebooks, and there are a truckload or two of more options for both players and the GM.

The way my GM did it when we switched, was to sit down with everyone, hand out new character sheets, and have the players completely rebuild their characters using whichever rulebooks you have/are allowing.

My advice is to *not* do anything piecemeal. Play awhile with the full rulebook - there is a lot in there, but not more so than any similar RPG core book. The GM and the players will need to read up on all of the changes, and familiarize themselves with the expanded setup. Use all the rules, and then houserule back from there.

Comment: Nice answer. What level were you when you switched?

Comment: Did you have a summary of the main differences? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19975/summary-of-differences-between-pathfinder-beginner-box-and-core-rules

Comment: @StuperUser We wanted switched by around level 2 or 3. About four games in, and the players were saying "This is nice, but we want more options." So by 5 when we ended, the DM broke out three copies of the core book, passed them around and the rest was a two year campaign of being complete badasses.