# Summary of differences between Pathfinder Beginner Box and Core Rules?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-beginner-box

Does anywhere have a good reference of the summary of differences between the Pathfinder Beginner Box rules and the Core Rules (which I believe are identical to [the online PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paizo provides a free [Basic Box Transitions](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8uqm) PDF to help you migrate from the beginner box to the main game.  Also there is an extensive [Forum Post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n1fk?Rule-Differences) detailing the differences - the summary is that the rules aren't different, just many rules are removed for the beginner box.

---

More detailed overview of the Forum post:

**Races**

- Only Dwarf, Elf and Human

**Classes**

- Cleric

  - Does not talk about Domains, but they are still there, they just auto pick them based on your god
  - No Domain spells
- Fighter

  - Auto Picks Weapon Focus and Weapon Specialization at levels 1 and 4, respectively
- Rogue

  - Smaller selection of Rogue Talents
- Wizard

  - Only Universalist, Evocation, Illusion
  - No Bonus feat at Level 5

**Skills & Feats**

- Reduced skill list, missing Appraise, Craft, Disguise, Escape Artist, Fly, Handle Animal, Intimidate, Knowledge: Engineering, Knowledge: Nobility, Knowledge: Planes, Linguistics, Perform, Sleight of Hand, Survival, and Use Magic Device
- Strongly reduced feat list

**Combat**

- No Attacks of Opportunity
- No Charging on Surprise
- No Combat Maneuvers or Combat Defense
- No Concentration checks to cast spells, you cannot cast spells when you are next to an enemy unless it is a touch attack spell
- No ranged attacks on adjacent targets

**General**

- Ability score Boosts grant a bonus to what the stat affects
- No Ability Damage or Drain

  - Poisons usually give the sickened condition or penalties on specific rolls
- No negative levels
- No max dex and no armor check penalty